# How can I set my font on calibri via iText7?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I try to set my text on Calibri on my Pdf document but that doesn't work. How can I set my font on calibri via iText7? Fontconstant class only has limited fonts.

Comment: it's explained right on the first chapter on the iText 7 Building Blocks (it's called Fonts): https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-1-introducing-fonts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, there is a whole [chapter on fonts](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-1-introducing-fonts) with more information on what you can do, what are the differences, etc.

In a nutshell, you use [CreateFont](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.9/classi_text_1_1_i_o_1_1_font_1_1_font_program_factory.html#ad95a1411eeb265d320aafb28ac83c170) to load your font file.

Something like this will allow you to set the font per [Paragraph](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.9/classi_text_1_1_layout_1_1_element_1_1_paragraph.html) element:

```
    FontProgram fontProgram =
        FontProgramFactory.CreateFont(@"C:\temp\calibri.ttf");
    PdfFont calibri = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(fontProgram, PdfEncodings.WINANSI);
    using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST)))
    {
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World!").SetFont(calibri));
    }
```

but you can also do it for the whole [Document](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.9/classi_text_1_1_layout_1_1_document.html):

```
    FontProgram fontProgram =
        FontProgramFactory.CreateFont(@"C:\temp\calibri.ttf");
    PdfFont calibri = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(fontProgram, PdfEncodings.WINANSI);
    using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST)))
    {
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
        document.SetFont(calibri);
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here just in case someone else like me comes across this and the provided solution isn't working.

The overload version of the used method that worked for me is the one below.

```
PdfFont calibri = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(fontProgram, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true);
```

Comment: You say *the provided solution isn't working.* How does it fail you?

Comment: @mkl Sorry, for not being specific, but the reason is - nothing specific happens. Font just isn't applied.

Comment: *"Font just isn't applied"* already is much more specific than *"solution isn't working"* which also can mean any kind of exception being thrown or result PDF containing arbitrary glyphs or something entirely different.